# How to display data from json in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I try to create simple app that generate random quote.
I created a function that (i think) get a data i want from json file. But when i try to pass that function to my App function i get Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

function Quote:

```js
function Quote (data) {
  var x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (103 - 1) + 1) );
  return fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {

    console.log(responseJson['quotes'][0]['author']);
    return responseJson['quotes'][x]['author'];
  })


  
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

App function:

```js
function App() {
  var text = '';
  return (
    
    <div id="quote-box">
      <div id="author"><Quote /></div>
      <button id="new-quote">New Quote</button>
      <a href="twitter.com" id="tweet-quote">Tweet</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `Quote` is not a `React` component. It's a function that returns a promise. I think you need to read the docs [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/your-first-component) to understand better how react components work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use useEffect to trigger a call at the start. And use useState to save the value. And then also add the same logic to the onClick.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function getQuote() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (103 - 1) + 1);
  return fetch(
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json"
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson["quotes"][0]["author"]);
      return responseJson["quotes"][x]["author"];
    })

    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

export default function App() {
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuote().then((newAuthor) => setAuthor(newAuthor));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id="quote-box">
      <div id="author">{author}</div>
      <button
        id="new-quote"
        onClick={() => getQuote().then((newAuthor) => setAuthor(newAuthor))}
      >
        New Quote
      </button>
      <a href="twitter.com" id="tweet-quote">
        Tweet
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Oh my god it works ^^ thanks you a lot i was trying to do this about 10 hours

Answer (score 0):

You can also archive this way. Create a custom hooks and used it.

```
import React from "react";

function useFetchQuote(newQuote) {
  const [author, setAuthor] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1) + 1);
    return fetch(
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson["quotes"][x]["author"]);
        setAuthor(responseJson["quotes"][x]["author"]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [newQuote]);

  return { author };
}

function App() {
  const [newQuote, setQuote] = React.useState(0);
  const { author } = useFetchQuote(newQuote);

  return (
    <div id="quote-box">
      <div id="author">{author}</div>
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={() => setQuote(newQuote + 1)}>
        New Quote
      </button>
      <a href="twitter.com" id="tweet-quote">
        Tweet
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a promise in `React` components will not work like what you are doing in your code. `React` components must return a `jsx`. For example in a file named `Quote.js`

```js
import * as React from 'react';

const url =
  'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json';

const Qoute = () => {
  const [quote, setQuote] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const randomNumber = 1; // Generate random number which is lesser or equal to data's length
        setQuote(data['quotes'][randomNumber]);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!quote) return <React.Fragment>Loading...</React.Fragment>;

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(quote)}</div>;
};

export default Qoute;
```

Then you just need to import it somewhere where you would like to use it and invoke it like this

```js
<Quote />
```

PS: I converted this from `typescript` if something is not working I'd be happy to help. And please remember to update the **line** where I place a comment. Goodluck, brother.